# Google App Engine + Flask + Stripe: Attribute Error: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'Customer'

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, flask, stripe-payments

I'm starting a mini blog for my honeymoon with Google App Engine, Flask and Stripe that we can send to family and friends. Everythings working great, except for Stripe.

Error Received:

```
File "/Users/MDev/Desktop/Steph_Max/Wedding/main.py", line 131, in charge
customer = stripe.Customer.create(
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'Customer'
```

This is the code line it's referring to in the error.

```
@app.route('/stripe')
def stripe():

return render_template('stripe.html', key=stripe_keys['publishable_key'])

@app.route('/charge', methods=['POST'])
def charge():
  # Amount in cents
  amount = 500

  customer = stripe.Customer.create(
    email = 'customer@example.com',
    card = request.form['stripeToken']
  )

  charge = stripe.Charge.create(
    customer=customer.id,
    amount=amount,
    currency='usd',
    description='Flask Charge'
  )

  return render_template('charge.html', amount=amount)
```

I have my `main.py` setup with just the default checkout as [documented](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/guides/flask) in Stripe docs:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from flask import send_from_directory
import stripe
import os


app = Flask(__name__)
#app.config['DEBUG'] = True

stripe_keys = {
    'secret_key' : os.environ['SECRET_KEY'],
    'publishable_key' : os.environ['PUBLISHABLE_KEY']
}



stripe.api_key = stripe_keys['secret_key']
```

My `index` page works (I've renamed it `stripe.html`) but the issue is just when it goes to the `charge` page. The script for the stripe button is working, I can submit a fake card, everything works except unto the charge page.

I'm on the noob side of noob so please be patient with me and if I'm missing something I'll update ASAP :)

Versions:

- stripe: stripe-1.14.0-py2.7.egg-info
- Python: 2.7
- GAE: 1.9.3

Comment: please provide full code. including the imports at the top of the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you have imported the stripe library and then defined a function with the same name.

Comment: Thx! I'm the worst! :D